# Using stripe CLI to test webhooks in windows dev machine

Tags: javascript, php, windows

I want to test stripe webhooks in my local windows dev machine, stripe docs mention stripe CLI as the best /easier way to test webhooks endpoints and sending fake events, I followed the docs to down load stripe CLI into my windows machine, I extracted the executable into my desktop but now I don't know how to properly excute commands in my cmd.

stripe.exe in my desktop, I first tried just simply clicking it, command prompt opened and showed message bellow, after a few seconds the command prompt closes.

```
This is a command line tool.

You need to open cmd.exe and run it from there.
```

After that I tried opening a CMD window and drag and dropping stripe.exe into the tab, I get the following list  of commands:

```
C:\Users\GABRIEL>C:\Users\GABRIEL\Desktop\stripe.exe
The official command-line tool to interact with Stripe.

Before using the CLI, you'll need to login:

  $ stripe login

If you're working on multiple projects, you can run the login command with the
--project-name flag:

  $ stripe login --project-name rocket-rides

Usage:
  stripe [command]

Webhook commands:
  listen                        Listen for webhook events
  trigger                       Trigger test webhook events

Stripe commands:
  logs                          Interact with Stripe API request logs
  status                        Check the status of the Stripe API

Resource commands:
  get                           Quickly retrieve resources from Stripe
  charges                       Make requests (capture, create, list, etc) on charges
  customers                     Make requests (create, delete, list, etc) on customers
  payment_intents               Make requests (cancel, capture, confirm, etc) on payment intents
  ...                           To see more resource commands, run `stripe resources help`

Other commands:
  completion                    Generate bash and zsh completion scripts
  config                        Manually change the config values for the CLI
  feedback                      Provide us with feedback on the CLI
  fixtures                      Run fixtures to populate your account with data
  help                          Help about any command
  login                         Login to your Stripe account
  logout                        Logout of your Stripe account
  open                          Quickly open Stripe pages
  samples                       Sample integrations built by Stripe
  serve                         Serve static files locally
  version                       Get the version of the Stripe CLI

Flags:
      --api-key string        Your API key to use for the command
      --color string          turn on/off color output (on, off, auto)
      --config string         config file (default is
                              $HOME/.config/stripe/config.toml)
      --device-name string    device name
  -h, --help                  help for stripe
      --log-level string      log level (debug, info, warn, error)
                              (default "info")
  -p, --project-name string   the project name to read from for config
                              (default "default")
  -v, --version               Get the version of the Stripe CLI

Use "stripe [command] --help" for more information about a command.

C:\Users\GABRIEL>
```

as you see I can't type any command, something like

```
stripe login
```

I'm left with no option to do anything with stripe cli in cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `cd` into the folder where you have stored `stripe.exe`. In your case that's:

```
C:\Users\GABRIEL> cd Desktop
```

Then you simply run stripe commands from there and it'll work. For instance:

```
C:\Users\GABRIEL\Desktop> stripe --help
```

OR

```
C:\Users\GABRIEL\Desktop> stripe login
```

Comment: It does not work now. throws error 'stripe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: You need to use Command Prompt, not Powershell

Answer (score 7):

To add the path of the stripe.exe file to your PATH environment variable on Windows, follow these steps:

Press the Windows key + R to open the Run dialog box.

Type "sysdm.cpl" in the Run dialog box and press Enter. This will open the System Properties window.

In the System Properties window, click on the "Advanced" tab.

Click on the "Environment Variables" button. This will open the Environment Variables window.

In the Environment Variables window, under the "System variables" section, scroll down and locate the "Path" variable. Select it and click on the "Edit" button.

In the Edit Environment Variable window, click on the "New" button to add a new entry.

Enter the full path to the directory where you have the stripe.exe file located. For example, if the stripe.exe file is in C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\the folder where stripe.exe is located, you would add 'C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\thefolderwherestripe.exeislocated' as a new entry.

Click "OK" to close all the windows.

Might not be needed but it is better to restart your computer

After restarting you should be able to access stripe cli globally,
try stripe -v in cmd

#Please Note: a lot of people are adding the path like so

this is the wrong way:
C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\foldername\stripe.exe

this is the correct way:
C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\stripefolder

Comment: The only correct answer for this question. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome, I was confused myself when I was following random tutorials and videos... why everyone was doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

".\stripe login" works not other in windows
i faced lots of issues by using stripe login , where that will not work after 100 attempts i tried .\stripe login and it worked finally

Comment: Please this link to learn how to write a good answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

- download the zip file
- extract to get the .exe inside it
- open cmd
- locate the file path
- try `stripe login`

If you are getting an error that says: "The command stripe was not found, but does exist in the current location. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\stripe"."

Then use:

> C:stripe_x_windows_64> `.\stripe login`

Answer (score 0):

we can use directly the file to run stripe login like this

plz go to the folder where you stored the **stripe.exe** file
then open terminal there and just type
**.\stripe.exe login**

Answer (score -1):

**Using system variables**

I know this is an old question, but i wanted to post this fairly simple answer which is useful also later on while bumping into these kind of problems.

I also do think the other answers are good options when using it once, but when using stripe commands consistently here is my solution:

1. Create a new folder at a place where you can access it easily for instance in your documents folder. I call my folder custom-commands you can call it however you want.
2. Create a new notepad file inside the folder and paste the following code in it:

```
@echo off

set cwd=%cd%
set stripePath=C:\Path\To\Stripe\Location
cd /d %stripePath% && stripe %*
cd /d %cwd%

set cwd=
set stripePath=
```

**Note the stripePath needs to be set to where your stripe.exe is located**

This scripts tells your cmd where stripe is located.

3. In the windows search function search `system variables`, open the app you will be prompted with a screen that looks like this:
   [image: System variables prompt]
4. Click `system variables` and then edit the `user path`: [image: User path]
5. Add a new path:
   [image]

6. The path needs to be the path to your newly created folder mine is called: custom-commands.
7. You might need to restart your computer and then just test it out by typing stripe in a cmd.

That's it! this also has one major benefit, because whenever you need something like this again you only have to create the .bat file and add your own script!